# How do I plot a function?

Tags: gnuplot

I have defined `f1(x) = 10 - 9 * x`. But, when I try `plot [x=0:1] f1` I get `undefined variable: f1` despite `print f1(.5)` gives me `5.5` and `plot [x=0:1] 10 - 9 * x` plots a nice graph. Why cannot you plot a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling gnuplot how to compute the function in the plot command.  Use

```
plot [x=0:1] f1(x)
```

When you don't include the `(x)` part, gnuplot assumes that you are referring to a variable (a constant) named `f1`, and thus throws the `undefined variable` error, as it can't find it.

In fact, you can have both a variable and a function with that same name (although I wouldn't recommend it - it's confusing), so gnuplot can't just assume that you want the function.  Additionally, if it was a function of a different variable, or of more than one variable, it would have no way of guessing how to compute it during the plot command.  Thus, you have to instruct gnuplot of how the function is computed.

See `help functions` for full details.